# Converting C function to C++ language

Tags: c++, file, syntax

Since this is my first encounter with the C programming language, it's not clear to me how I'm going to convert a piece of code to C++. I know that this code can be used in C ++ but I want to work exclusively on the syntax of the C++ language.

Here is my code:

```
FILE *f;
char name[10],surname[10],j[10];
f=fopen("Marks.txt","r");
fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
```

I want to open the file using:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("Marks.txt");
```

But then I don't know what to use instead of the fscanf function because I can no longer use FILE *f;

Comment: [`input >> n;`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) ?

Comment: Or `std::getline(input, n);` Depends on the contents.

Comment: Did you read references? (for example, [ifstream - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/))

Comment: Replace character arrays with `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C++ way to do it, though you technically can still use that C code.

```cpp
#include <ifstream>

int main() {
  std::string str;
  int i;
  double d;
  char c_str[10];

  std::ifstream input;
  input.open("Marks.txt");
  input >> str; // reads a word of text into str
  input >> i;   // assuming there is a valid integer after the first line, reads it into i
  input >> d;   // assuming there is a valid double after that, reads it into d
  // reads up to 9 characters + a '\0', stopping if it reaches a period
  input.get(c_str, 10-1, '.');
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: `input >> str;` reads not a line but (something like) a word. It will stop reading at whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
int main()
{
    // Let the constructor handle opening the file.
    std::ifstream input("Marks.txt");
    int n = 0;
    std::string s;
    double d = 0;
    // Read an int, followed by a string, followed by a double.
    if (input >> n >> s >> d)
    {
        std::cout << "Success!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failure!\n";

    }
    // The destruction of 'input' will close the file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First to do is make a `std::fstream` object then open the file of your choice, you can do any lines (in sequence) of the following:

```cpp
// Option 1
std::fstream input; // create the object
input.open("Marks.txt", ios::in); // since this is a `std::fstream` object, you'll need to specify `ios::in` for input operations

// Option 2
std::ifstream input; // create the object, this time dedicated to input
input.open("Marks.txt"); // no need to specify `ios::in`

// Option 3
std::fstream input("Marks.txt", ios::in); // you can directly open the file using the constructor, but specify `ios::in`

// Option 4
std::ifstream input("Marks.txt"); // directly opening the file using the constructor with the object dedicated to input
```

Next, you'll use `operator>>` or `std::getline()` to get input from the stream

```cpp
// first declare the variables
std::string str1 = ""; // use std::string in C++ instead C-style strings (char[])
int ing1 = 0;

// Option 1
input >> str1; // this parses the contents of the file into str1, until the space
/*
Suppose "Marks.txt" has this inside it:

Hello World

The first content of the file until a space is "Hello", this string parsed into str1
*/

// Option 2
ing1 = input.get() // this parses only one character then turns it into an integer (destination type) into ing1
/*
Suppose "Marks.txt" has this inside it:

1234567890

ing1 will bear the value 1.

however, like std::iostream, this does not convert the character to it's integral value (ASCII, automatically) thus when:

abcdefghij

ing1 will have the value 0, since 'a' is not an integer
*/

// Option 3
input.getline(str1, 6); // this will parse into str1 six (6) characters, including spaces (not sure with control characters)
/*
Suppose "Marks.txt" has this inside it:

StackOverflow

"StackO" will be parsed into str1
*/
```

*Note: this operations differ when stream is opened in binary mode (`ios::binary`) and be careful with `std::getline()` this may overload the buffer (especially when specified with `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`)*

EDIT: **IMPORTANT** **close the stream after using.**

```cpp
// some operations here
// file is no longer needed -> close it
input.close();
```